# Invalid column name in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have an ASP.MET application. I performed the tutorial on code first migrations. When I executed the commands, the following code was generated for the user table:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    ApplicationId = c.Guid(nullable: false),    
                    Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                    EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = c.String(),
                    SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                    LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: true),
                    UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    Discriminator = c.String(),
                    LegacyPasswordHash = c.String(),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");
```

My problem is that I don't need some columns. So, I removed the code from those columns and updated my DB. But, when I try to authenticate a user, I get this error:

> Invalid column name 'EmailConfirmed'.
>   Invalid column name 'PhoneNumberConfirmed'.
>   Invalid column name 'TwoFactorEnabled'.
>   Invalid column name 'LockoutEndDateUtc'.
>   Invalid column name 'LockoutEnabled'.
>   Invalid column name 'AccessFailedCount'.

But these columns no longer exist because I deleted them.

Or, is it possible to put it back and assign them default values ​​for example:

```
EmailConfirmed = false
PhoneNumberConfirmed = false
```

to avoid making an insertion when creating a user. I use EF 6.2.0

Need help please.

Comment: Have you removed them (properties) from your model class? ??

Comment: @Sonal Bokar, here is my class: ` public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public User()
        {

    }

        public System.Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
       }
}`

Comment: EmailConfirmed, PhoneNumberConfirmed, TwoFactorEnabled, LockoutEndDateUtc, LockoutEnabled, AccessFailedCount are in IdentityUser class which is derived by User. So, this will be sent by default to ASPNetUsers table row manipulation by EntityFramework

Comment: Why did you removed this columns?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that information. I removed them because when I want to register a new user, they must be specified in the SQL query because they are not nullable.

Comment: Should i give them default values ​​in the User class?

Comment: No need for default values. I guess the default for boolean is false if no value is provided

Comment: First, you shouldn't mess with Identity that way. Second, don't hack the migration - change your classes (Code First). Third, use a [UserManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn613290(v%3Dvs.108)) to modify identity users.

Comment: ok @Steve Greene, I understood the first two suggestions. But what do you mean y modify identity users. Because I have a userManager class that I already use

Comment: OK, if you are not directly updating the table and using a UserManager you should be OK. You can't just remove fields you think are not needed. What problems were you having with UserManager?

Comment: I don't have problems with UserManager. I tried to update users table manually but after all the explanations, I understand that it is not correct